# PhantomJS exited unexpectedly with exit code 3221225477

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, phantomjs, grunt-contrib-jasmine

i'm using Phantomjs combined with grunt and jasmine to run unit tests for AngularJs application. I'm experiencing strange behavior when the Unit tests become too many. In my case 754/755 unit tests. The unit tests run fail with the following message

> Running PhantomJS...ERROR
>
> > 0 [ '' ]
> >     Warning: PhantomJS exited unexpectedly with exit code 3221225477. Use --force to continue.
>
> Aborted due to warnings.

When i comment out some old tests, so their number become less then 754/755 everything works just fine. When the tests becomes too many(more then 754/755) this error appears. I believe it could be something it the memory allocation of the PhantomJS, but i couldn't find anything connected to this error code - 3221225477 and i couldn't be sure. I haven't find any solution about it only the workaround with commenting unit tests. The problem occurs on Windows 7 machine, the same test build works on MacOs without problem, no matter how many unit tests are there, so it is also connected with the OS.

I would appreciate any help suggestions about it, Thanks!

Comment: I found a solution for my problem.

I've updated phantomjs to version 2.1.1 and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe PhantomJS has run out of memory.

1. Download and extract PhantomJS 2.X from
   http://phantomjs.org/download.html
2. Set PHANTOMJS_BIN variable to the
   phantomjs.exe path.
3. Run your unit test.

Comment: I've updated phantomjs to version 2.1.1 and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and what I did to fix it was to change package.json and include in devDependecies the following modules:

```
"karma-phantomjs-launcher": "1.0.0"
"phantomjs-prebuilt": "2.1.12"
```

and re-run `npm install`